# Resharper DotCover not working on new test project

Tags: .net-core, resharper, dotcover

An existing dotNet core 2.0 solution was working fine with dotCover. 
I added a new project and a new test project for it but dotCover is not working for this new one. 
It just does not show any coding covered or percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test project was created after upgrading Visual Studio to 2019 and it used the new Dotnet core 3.0 instead of 2.0. 
After aligning the versions the issue was solved.